# Using LINQ on XML - join is very slow

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I am custom writing something to help us take two valid XML files, compare them, and generate a sort of list of inserts/updates/deletes that we are passing to another system for data integration.

I've never touched LINQ in my life, so this is my first attempt at it. It works fine, so I started stretching the limits to test performance. As currently I may only be dealing with salaried employees my data sets were small, but considering one day this system may incorporate hourly employees, I want to test a ceiling of ~100k xml entities.

What this does is take a before.xml file and an after.xml file, iterate though a defined entity, and hopefully pull out any changes values.

I had ~100k rows processing in 8-9 seconds. I don't know of that's a bad thing, but it's a totally acceptable number for us. The problem is that I was only testing between 1-3 updates. Inserts/deletes are easy and quick. Updates though, every time I add a new one to detect, it adds a whole second onto the calculation time!

I can only assume my very first LINQ query is to blame. Here's what I have. Is there something blatantly inefficient or wrong with it that I should learn to avoid?:

```
////////////for sake of this demo//////////////
string entityNode = "book";
string guidAttribute = "id";
///////////////////////////////////////////////
IEnumerable<XElement> befores = XElement.Load(beforeXMLFile).Elements(entityNode);
IEnumerable<XElement> afters = XElement.Load(afterXMLFile).Elements(entityNode);

//Updates/changes
IEnumerable<XElement> updates =
    from afterChild in afters.Descendants()
    join beforeChild in befores.Descendants() on 
                                       new
                                       {
                                           ((XElement)afterChild).Parent.Attribute(guidAttribute).Value,
                                           ((XElement)afterChild).Name
                                       }
                                       equals new
                                       {
                                           ((XElement)beforeChild).Parent.Attribute(guidAttribute).Value,
                                           ((XElement)beforeChild).Name
                                       }
    where (((XElement)afterChild).Value != ((XElement)beforeChild).Value)
    select ((XElement)afterChild);
```

And my XML (ugly test, ignore) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<catalog>
    <book id="bk1">
        <author>Le, Kellie T.</author>
        <title>amet,</title>
        <genre>Horror</genre>
        <price>68 590</price>
        <publish_date>09-01-2014</publish_date>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur</description>
        <id>1</id>
    </book>
    <book id="bk2">
        <author>Hoffman, Leonard H.</author>
        <title>molestie</title>
        <genre>Romance</genre>
        <price>26 761</price>
        <publish_date>03-10-2013</publish_date>
        <description>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. Curabitur sed tortor. Integer aliquam adipiscing lacus. Ut nec</description>
        <id>2</id>
    </book>

.... plus another 100k of these with random data

</catalog>
```

My goal was to join any child elements of my main entity elements (like "book") on the name of the field element and the ID of it's parent WHERE the values of before != after. Again, this works exactly as I want it to, but I suspect my join is slow as all hell.

Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Descendants` return everything down the document tree. If you have 100k `book` elements, it returns almost 1 million elements, because each has 9 child elements. It gives you 900,000 X 900,000 = 810,000,000,000 pairs as a `join` input, and that many times your `join` condition is evaluated. I'm not surprised it's very slow.

You should no use `Descendants` unless you really need to. Use `Elements` instead. I wrote an article about that a while ago: [Why (or when) you should/shouldn't use Descendants() method](http://mjuraszek.blogspot.com/2013/08/why-not-use-descendants-method.html).

***Update***

How about splitting the query into two? First, join on `book`s on `id`, and then try to get updated values from its elements?

```
var pairs =
    from a in afters
    join b in befores
    on (string)a.Attribute(guidAttribute) equals (string)b.Attribute(guidAttribute)
    select new { a, b };

var updates =
    from p in pairs
    from ac in p.a.Elements()
    from bc in p.b.Elements()
    where ac.Name == bc.Name && (string)ac != (string)bc
    select ac;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response - I know those numbers look high, but as I need to compare every child element with it's corresponding element between two files, don't I need to use Descendants()? How would I achieve the same results by only getting their parents via Elements()?

Comment: I've updated my answer with suggested solution. It should dramatically reduce number of comparisons.

Comment: What is the purpose of using two queries? These could easily be merged.

Comment: @CoryNelson Yes, they could. But it does not change anything, because of LINQ deferred execution. In my opinion, it would only made it less readable.

Comment: Thanks @MarcinJuraszek, your snippet worked on its first go and does reduce the time taken overall. However, it did still seem to increase the calculation time by 1 second per "update"/change found. But THEN I found out some code below that I did not include here was a bit optimized which further reduced this number. It now takes around 5 seconds total, which each 6 random updates adding around another second onto the total.

For the meantime, we won't be anywhere near 100k rows, so most of what we'll be doing should be around 0-2 seconds tops in the meantime. Thanks for the help!